# How can I resolve package dependency conflict?

Tags: apt, package-management

When I enter the command:

```
sudo apt install libstdc++6:i386
```

I get the output:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6 : Breaks: libstdc++6:i386 (!= 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04) but 8-20180414-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-8-base:i386 (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 is to be installed
                   Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 is to be installed
 E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

This answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/1104999/772004) shows that 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 refers to the "bionic-updates" repository, while 8-20180414-1ubuntu2 refers to the "bionic" repository.

Why are these packages in conflict? What does it mean that a different package is "to be installed"? Finally, how can I resolve the issue?

**Edit:**
I did figure out a solution. I needed to add the bionic-updates and bionic-security repositories to my sources.list file. Also, Sophos AV was causing some trouble with apt. Once I changed sources.list and uninstalled Sophos AV, I was able to update and resolve all dependency issues.

Comment: You didn't say what OS/release you are running, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libstdc%2B%2B6 shows what each release expects but you have packages (thus sources) that don't match any; and what is your architecture; x86_64?

Comment: Is your system fully up-to-date? (Probably not.)

Comment: By the way, when Apt says a package "is to be installed", it means it is the package you requested to be installed, or a dependency thereof.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, and yes, its an x86_64 architecture. My settings say I'm up to date, but maybe I'm missing something. And thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix this, I needed to edit my /etc/apt/sources.list file.

I had only the line:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe restricted multiverse
```

and I needed to add the lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe restricted multiverse
```

to add the bionic-security and bionic-updates repositories. Afterward I still had some trouble, which turned out to be related to Sophos AV. After unintstalling Sophos AV,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

fixed all the dependencies.